# GeckoDriver is not entering value for Firstname field within Firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, geckodriver

Firefox driver is not entering a value for `Firstname` field.
I'm trying the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id=\JNHGYHG\"]")).sendsKeys("Hello");
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you "" are wrong just by looking at your xpath assuming you have the the rest right try this:  driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="\JNHGYHG\"])).sendsKeys("Hello");

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: Can you please post html?

Comment: It should be `sendKeys `. You have a small mistake.

Comment: sharing html will be better , but try this one driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='\JNHGYHG\']")).sendsKeys("Hello");

Comment: Your current code presented won't build. Please fix it and update the question. Also, why are you using an XPath for just an ID when you can just use `By.id("JNHGYHG")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see any difference.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='JNHGYHG']")).sendKeys("Hello");
```

Comment: can you please share html here?

Comment: well I cannot share HTML due to privacy. so that's why I asked ho can I run the script with this kind of ID. because I am getting an error message org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #JNHGYHG

Comment: Correct you can share the partial html snapshot only the part it is impacted.Come on that you can do.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("JNHGYHG")).sendKeys("Hello");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: That is not html.I am asking when you inspect the element provide that element html part.Not the java code which you have written.

Comment: how to handle dynamic changing elements in XPath?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your code trial there is an error within the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have used.

### Solution

You can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *id* attribute:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("JNHGYHG")).sendKeys("Hello");
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#JNHGYHG")).sendKeys("Hello");
  ```
- Using *xpath* (option A):

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='JNHGYHG']")).sendKeys("Hello");
  ```
- Using *xpath* (option B):

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"JNHGYHG\"]")).sendKeys("Hello");
  ```

Comment: I tried all above options and getting this message.  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to convert data to an object

Comment: Whenever I am running my test case in Firefox I am getting cookies popup I want to remove it how can I do this? We use cookies to make your experience better. To comply with the new e-Privacy directive, we need to ask for your consent to set the cookies. Learn more.